# Unserialize returns false

Tags: php, serialization

I am serializing data stored in a database:

> a:10:{s:4:"name";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"excluded";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:8:"keywords";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"excluded";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:11:"description";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"excluded";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:3:"sku";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"excluded";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:12:"manufacturer";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"excluded";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:11:"programname";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"excluded";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:12:"dataprovider";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"excluded";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:11:"lastupdated";a:1:{s:5:"value";N;}s:8:"currency";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:0:"";}s:5:"price";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}}

When I unserialize, it returns empty data but when I echo the data and copy the o/p from the browser and put it statically for unserialize, it works fine.

Can anybody tell me what may be the issue?

Comment: Works for me. Show us how you're unserializing it.

Comment: the column in the db might be cutting some of the data off the end

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/5alN7MLc)

Comment: Three upvotes? Pshaw! Make a testcase because, as @Mihai has demonstrated, _there is no problem here_.

Answer (score 5):

What you have supplied above does and should work.

When saving serialized data in a database, set the length of the column to a very high amount.

If you think the serialized data will be no more than 1000 characters then add half onto it and you should be fine.

You would want to use `VARCHAR(1500)` for serializable data that you think will be around 1000 characters long.

I can almost guarantee that your problem is because the database is storing your serialized data and clipping it so that it can fit into your column.

Comment: In my case, it was `BLOB` column (65535 bytes), which turned out to be not enough. Changing it to `MEDIUMBLOB` helped.